# you are being conditioned

Tags: sentence-meaning

> You are being conditioned into feeling as you do.
>
> A lot of pressures are encouraging you to worry about your appearance .

What does the first sentence mean?
I think  it  means a lot of pressure make you to be  in a sad condition according to the second sentence.

Comment: Have you looked up the meaning of *conditioned* (or *condition* / *conditioning*)?

Comment: I want to know the meaning "are being conditioned into feeling"?

Comment: Your question as it stands is off-topic, since you given no indication that you have tried to answer it yourself.

Comment: OK.I have edited.Please check and give your opinion.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at [definition 1.1 for the verb "to conditon"](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/condition) you'll find:

> Train or accustom to behave in a certain way or to accept certain circumstances.

Your sentence means:

> You are being *trained to feel the way that you feel*.